# WP - Update failed. The response is not a valid JSON response + the table is missing from the database

Tags: html, wordpress, url, post

I got an error refreshing information on a page on my WordPress site.

Error(WP - Update failed. The response is not a valid JSON response):
[image]

Console:
[image]

Network:
[image]

Also, for some reason, a table with links disappears from the database. I checked the rest and they work (for example, a table with links and a table with users)
[image]

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change a type of url to simple(where ?page=1). And problem is resolved.